# Statistic to measure grouping (or intensity) of observations

Tags: time-series, clustering

I'm looking for a statistical technique that can measure the level of grouping or intensity of observations.  I'm not sure what the proper terminology is, so I will try to explain my question through some examples.

Say I have a dataset with three groups of twenty observations.  In practice, these will be some kind of time series.

```
Set 1:  0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0
Set 2:  0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
Set 3:  0, 8, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8, 1, 1
```

The three sets each represent a time series of observations.  The first is clustered and clumped together - the 1's and 2's are adjacent in the time series.

The second set is less clustered and more random.

The third set is heavily clustered and also more intense than the first set (the observed values are higher).

I'm looking for some kind of statistical technique that can evaluate the clustering and intensity relative to the other sets.

For example, is there a statistical measure that would say "Set 1 and set 3 are more clustered than set 2"?  Is there a measure that would say "Set 3 is more intense than set 1 or especially set 2"?  (The intensity question is more nuanced than simply taking the average of the set... I guess some kind of average of non-zero numbers might work, but I'm curious to see what others think).

Please let me know if this question makes sense.  I'm using an abstract example of something.

---

**Update:**
I want to clarify what I mean by clustering.  Each observation in the time series represents a result on some scale.  For example, the scale might be 0 to 10.  The higher the number, the more significant the event is on the scale.  I'll try to give an example to show how I'm thinking about the issue.

The numbers could represent a person's level of anxiety on a given series of days.  A zero would indicate no anxiety, whereas a 10 would be a significant event.  It's a sliding scale.

My goal is to measure two things:  How intense is a person's anxiety when it occurs and does the appearance of anxiety mean that further episodes are more likely in the immediate future.

In this example, clustering is the appearance of non-zero numbers on consecutive (or near consecutive) days.  Intensity is how far above zero the numbers go when they do occur.

In practical terms, I could then compare people and say whether or not their anxiety is predicted by prior days' anxiety.  I could also compare the acuteness of anxiety among different people, regardless of clustering.

These are the kinds of statements I want to make:

- "Person 3 has higher levels of anxiety (when it occurs) relative to Person 1 and 2"
- "Person 1 is more likely to experience anxiety on a day after reporting anxiety than Person 2"
- "Person 2 has lower levels of anxiety (when it occurs) relative to the rest of the group"
- "Person 3 has higher anxiety relative to the group (when it occurs) and is more likely to experience anxiety on a day after reporting anxiety the day before."

Hopefully this helps explain what I'm looking at.

Comment: It's not yet clear what aspects of your data you consider relevant to "clustering." Is it some combination of being separated by zeros, or separated by multiple zeros, or attaining "high" values above zero, or something else? If you could explain what these data represent, that would help make your situation more understandable.

Comment: You can do something like a [runs test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35d.htm). But a more sophisticated approach is probably to fit the ARMA structure of each series & look for the specific properties you are interested in (eg a stronger MA structure?).

Comment: @gung How would a runs test exploit the sense of "intensity"?  Out of curiosity, what aspect of these data suggests they might be fit well to any MA model?  I would have thought this couldn't be done with such integral, zero-inflated data.  (But maybe you have a GLM generalization in mind or something like that?)

Comment: I'm not sure what "intensity" is here, @whuber. Maybe those were poor suggestions; I was just suggesting ideas that came to mind. The idea of the runs test is to see if the data are more 'streaky' than you'd expect--too many 0's in a row followed by too many non-0's. But that's a *test,* not a measure, so I guess that was off-base. Re ARMA, you're right that you'd need some sort of count time series model; you could look to see if you had intervals w/ low lambda & intervals w/ high lambda, the magnitude of the shift b/t the lambdas & the length of the period. (Or maybe that's off-base, too.)

Comment: @gung "Off-base" and "creative" can be difficult to distinguish :-).  Thank you for elaborating on your ideas.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I will update the question and try to clarify.